# append typed text to link url ( live ) - demo included

Tags: jquery

Hi I am just doing user profiles, and figured would be cool to allow them to add a facebook link to their profile, and preview it on click, or in a modal window, but thats the easy bit.

I have done a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/kw7gH/1/

Essentially, I want user to type a facebook ID into the input box, show a preview and then the typed text they did gets appended to the href link so that on click it tests that url.

js is:

```
$(function(){   
    $(".facebookID").keyup(function(){
            var facebookID=$(this).val();
            $(".facebookID_preview").html(facebookID);
            return false;
    });
});
```

basically I want to add the typed text to the href link so if they typed stackoverflow , the link would be http://facebook.com/stackoverflow

Comment: Free demo! Can't resist. Also, what problem are you having? Are you stuck on getting a nicely formatted URL into your `<a href="">`?

Comment: basically I want to add the typed text to the href link so if they typed stackoverflow , the link would be http://facebook.com/stackoverflow

Comment: Some other fella did CHANGE , i replied and then his reply disappeared .. weird. He must have deleted it, yep Tomm has done good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding

```
$("div a").attr("href","http://facebook.com/"+$(".facebookID_preview").text());
```

before the `return false` statement? Note that the selector for the link probably needs to be a bit more specific in a real webpage environment...

Comment: @422 There is likely to be more than one `div a` on the page; Tomm is talking about turning your selector into something that will only select one link.

Comment: so what would I do to make that more dynamic and robust, my selector is a href so what do I do for div a ? do i add a ID to it so its something like div a fb ? and div a tw ?

Comment: god I am thick, I cant believe I didnt realise ... grr All Sorted :) thanks mate. I added like this: $("div a.fb") and $("div a.tw") and gave href the same classes

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    window.open($(this).attr('href') + '/' + $('.facebookID_preview').html());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kw7gH/5/

Comment: that works, as far as link goes but link preview in activity bar doesnt display the full url. Any idea why

Comment: Because the href still save facebook.com, the navigation happens later in the javascript